# How to access a table within a range nested in another table?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ms-office

In order to access the single table within a range (say, rngOuter) I used:
   tblOuter = rngOuter.Tables[1];
After I placed a nested table within a range (say, rngInner) within that outer range's table, I found that:
   tblInner = rngInner.Tables[1];
did not work. rngInner.Tables[1] references tblOuter, rather than the table within itself.
In fact, Tables collection of rngInner has only one element, and that is tblOuter. In order to access tblInner, I have to get at tblOuter.Range.Tables[1].

Does anyone know if I am making a mistake, or that's the way it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK "that's the way it is", but you can look for cells that contain tables by using Cell.Tables rather than Cell.Range.Tables. e.g. to look for cells in the current selection that contain tables you could use

```
Sub listInnerTables()
Dim c As Cell
Dim r As Range
Dim t As Table
Dim tcount As Long
Set r = Selection.Range
If r.Tables.Count > 0 Then
  tcount = 0
  For Each t In r.Tables
    tcount = tcount + 1
    For Each c In t.Range.Cells
      If c.Range.InRange(r) Then
        If c.Tables.Count > 0 Then
          Debug.Print "Table: " & CStr(tcount) & _
            vbTab & " Row: " & CStr(c.RowIndex) & _
            vbTab & " Col: " & CStr(c.ColumnIndex) & _
            vbTab & " Table count: " & CStr(c.Tables.Count)
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
End If
Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up identifying the container cell and doing something like this.