# Apply formatting for nested tables

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

In my document, I have table style called "Small". And here is the macro, which will change the font size in each table of this style:

```
Sub FormatTables()
    Dim t As Table
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        If t.Style = "Small" Then
            t.Range.Font.Size = 8
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is, that it doesn't work for nested tables. In picture shown below, black table is "Normal", blue table is "Small". How it could be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Checking (eg) `t.Range.Tables.Count` will tell you if `t` contains any nested tables: then you can loop over those...

Comment: @TimWilliams Well, I tried, for example [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105718/how-to-access-a-table-within-a-range-nested-in-another-table), but currently can't understand how it could be adapted in my case...

Comment: @TimWilliams Here is my [semi-working version](https://jsfiddle.net/n5b00mod/). But, it works only for the 1st level of nested tables. For example, if I have table Normal, then second table Normal inside first one, and then table Small inside second Normal, this Small table will not be formatted. As I understand, it should be used `Do While ... Loop` here, but I can't understand how exactly it should be done.

Comment: I will post something a bit later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should process every table, even those tables nested to arbitrary depth.

```
Sub FormatTables()

    Dim t As Table, col As New Collection
    Dim n As Table

    'add all top-level table(s) to collection
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        col.Add t
    Next

    'process each table from the collection
    Do While col.Count > 0
        Set t = col(1) '<< reference the first table from the collection
        col.Remove 1   '<< remove it from collection
        Debug.Print "Table has " & t.Rows.Count & " rows", t.Style

        If t.Style = "Small" Then t.Range.Font.Size = 8

        'gather any nested table(s) for checking
        For Each n In t.Tables
            col.Add n
        Next n
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to solve this problem all the day.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar question. I did a lot of research before posting this. I created an empty document, inserted two small tables, nested one of them with still another table, and tested with the following codes:

```
Sub testtest()

Dim aRange As Range

MsgBox ThisDocument.Tables.Count
For Each oTable In ThisDocument.Tables
    For Each oCell In oTable.Range.Cells
        Set aRange = oCell.Range
        aRange.MoveEnd Count:=-2
        aRange.Select
        MsgBox aRange.Tables.Count
        MsgBox oCell.Tables.Count
    Next oCell
Next oTable



End Sub
```

Explaination: First, the reason that I moved the end of the cell's range by -1 and after that by -2 is to exclude the dubious `Chr(13)` and `Chr(7)` at the end of a cell. That explained, now, through the above test, I found that `aRange.Tables.Count` is always 1 (and never 0) even when no table is nested in the cell. It puzzled me until I examined `oCell.Tables.Count` through the `MsgBox`. -- The difference between `oTable.Tables` vs. `oTable.Range.Tables` is similar. -- A nested table is nested to the parent `Table` and it is nested to the upper level `Cell`, but not to the table's or the cell's `Range`!

Therefore, I think the selected answer does give a fantastic way of taking advantage of `Collection` (which is unique to vba, I seem to remember reading so somewhere), and does work to solve the the problem, but, it has not pointed out the "hinge" or "knack" of the problem. Once again, the "knack" is that you can "catch" the nested tables using `oTable.Tables` but not `oTable.Range.Tables`; in comparison, you can "catch" the cells in a table using `oTable.Range.Cells` but not `oTable.Cells`.